# Changing the format of a PHP array to allow looping in a smarty tempate

Tags: php, arrays, loops, format, smarty

First post - Have been researching and struggling for days but I am unabl to resolve the following issue where I have added a second Select query to do some distance calculations from my starting point to destinations within a certain range I am getting the output ok but not in a fromat i can use -
I have an existing script that outputs an array and passes this to a smarty template - this works fine  so i have used this to debug whats going wrong in my first attemp.

I am using a `printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($myarrayname, true));` to debug and have the following output

```
Array
(
    [firm] => company name 1
    [loc1] => Inverness
    [distance] => 0.800791320271485
)

Array
(
    [firm] => company name 2
    [loc1] => Inverness
    [distance] => 0.972151789782665
)

Array
(
    [firm] => company name 3
    [loc1] => Inverness
    [distance] => 1.04042401681383
)
```

etc etc
however my known working output produces
 the follow with one index and combines the [firm] and [loc1] together (but ommiting the index name)

```
Array
(
    [html] => company name 1 Inverness
)

Array
(
    [html] => company name 2 Inverness
) 

Array
(
    [html] => company name 3 Inverness 
)
```

Can anyone suggest how I can convert this array to the format shown.
Hope there is enough info here - did not want to splater ther page with irrelevent stuff

Here is the Code

```
// Start of Nearby query
$lat = trim($_REQUEST['lat']);
$lng = trim($_REQUEST['lng']);

$lat = (!empty($lat)? $lat : 57.45666); // starting point Latitude
$lng = (!empty($lng)? $lng : -4.22137);// starting point Longitude

$HelpQuery = sprintf("SELECT firm, loc1, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( %s ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( longit ) - radians( %s ) ) + sin( radians( %s ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM $my_table WHERE state='apr'  HAVING distance > 0.01  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1,5",$lat,$lng,$lat);

$HelpResult = mysql_query($HelpQuery);
$result = array();
$result['html'] = "";

if($HelpResult)
{
    while($Helprow = mysql_fetch_assoc($HelpResult))
            printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($Helprow, true)); // Prints on     3 lines each one having its own index- needs combiing to one index

    {
            $Helprow['distance'] = round($Helprow['distance'],2);
            $result['html'][] = $Helprow; 
    }
}
else
{
    $result['html'] = "Error";
}
// End of listing nearby  MOD
```

Comment: You sure this isn't an SQL question? Looks to me you're using a different query... **edit** Or not, since the arrays are assoc. Where do the arrays come from? What function?

Comment: I guess its probably something to do with your smarty code (which is trying to output your array as html.. need to see code

Comment: hi @Rudie added th code to the main post (could not figure out how to as a comment. )You may be right been at it for so long may have gone down the wrong track and problenm may be higher up. It is a diffent query that calculats distance within the query - I am getting the right answers from the query just not in the right format. I have not executed the smarty code here but happy that its just a replication of existing code once the format is right

Comment: Btw: You can `ROUND` numbers in MySQL. (Could save you a loop if you do.) [See manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Comment: @Rudie Thanks - tried that and works well so will remove that old bit of code now :)

Comment: So you live on Green Dr, Inverness?

Comment: @Rudie sadly not just an arbitrary set of co-ordinates for testing that will eventually be set to a variable pulling in "current" location as the page loads on a particular record. Good news just fixed the problem with thanks to yourself clearing out some coding clutter - will post the answer next - Thanks again

Comment: No problem. If it's a decent solution, post the answer yourself, so this question will at least have an answer.

Comment: @Rudie tried to post  and answer but as a new user I "have to wait 8 hours before submitting and answer" will try again later today with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions and pointer I have now resolved this issue with the new code pasted below. The output to display records within a given distance from the source can [found here](http://www.bnbscotland.co.uk/live/Eildon_Guest_House-3052.html) towards the bottom of the page. The source latitude and longitude are pulled onto each page as a variable.

```
// Start of Nearby Accommodation query
$lat =  $vs_current_listing['lat'];
$lng = $vs_current_listing['longit'];


$firm_loop = sprintf("SELECT firm, loc1, id, ROUND( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( %s ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( longit ) - radians( %s ) ) + sin( radians( %s ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ,2) AS distance FROM $my_table WHERE state='apr' AND record_set='xxxx' HAVING distance BETWEEN 0.01 and 20  ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1,20",$lat,$lng,$lat);
$firm_loop = mysql_query($firm_loop);
for($x=0;$x<mysql_num_rows($firm_loop);$x++){ 
 $f_img = mysql_fetch_assoc($firm_loop);  
$f_firm[mod_firm]  = str_replace(" ","_",$f_img[firm]);
$vs_listfirm[$x][html] = "<a href=\"./$f_firm[mod_firm]-$f_img[id].html\"    title='$f_img [firm]'>" .$f_img[firm]." - ".$f_img[loc1]."  - ".$f_img[distance]."  miles  </a>"; 
}
$tpl-> assign('vs_listfirm',$vs_listfirm); 
// End of listing nearby  MOD
```

The section of the smarty template displaying the code is shown below, color fonts and formating have been ommited to show basic code.

```
{html_table_adv loop=$vs_listfirm cols=2 inner=cols table_attr='width=90% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1'} [[html]] {/html_table_adv}
```